# nodeJS: creating an array inside an existing JSON object and injecting into it

Tags: json, node.js

Say I had a JSON object constructed this way:

```
var obj = {
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2"
};
```

and I had one different object:

```
var newObj = {"email": "you@hoo.com"};
```

What If I wanted to inject the content of `newObj` into `obj` in a way that'll look like this in the end:

```
{
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2"
  "to": [{
            "email": "you@hoo.com",
            "defaultValue": "111"       <-- this is always constant
        }]
};
```

how can this be done?

Comment: are you still facing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say JSON you're implying that it is JSON, not a javascript object. JSON is a serialize js object. You just have an object. An array is an object. The array object has method `Array.prototype.push`. This allows you to push a single value to an array. To join there's another method `concat`, which will concatenate an array with another array or a value.

*Array.prototype.push(...)*

```
var arr=[1,2];
arr.push(3);
console.log(arr); //outputs: [1, 2, 3]
```

*Array.prototype.concat(...)*

```
var arr=[1,2];
var result=arr.concat([3,4]);
result=result.concat(5);
console.log(result); //outputs: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
obj.to = [];
newObj.defaultValue = "111";
obj.to.push(newObj);
```

See if that works for ya.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
obj['to']=newObj;
obj['to']['defaultValue']="111";
```